# Primefaces commandButton not working properly

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

I want, when i press the commandButton, to refresh my page (all inputText boxes, all checkBoxes to be empty, as if the page is reloaded. 
I tried with update="@requestForm", update=":requestForm", update="@all" ajax="false", update="@([id$=requestForm])", but no success...

This is the code for my commandButton:

```
  <h:commandButton value="Save" id="saveBtn"
                        actionListener="#{requestBean.addRequest()}" ajax="false" />
```

My form has id = "requestForm". Any ideas?

Comment: please post more code, specifically the entire <h:form>...</h:form>

edit* actually don't do that. I think jsf is smart enough to keep values in text boxes on a POST. In your backing bean method `#{requestBean.addRequest()}` you may need to reset all values to null / blank

Comment: you can also look at `resetValues` for <f:ajax>

Comment: First of all you are using h:commandButton. h:commandButton does not have a ajax attribute so no need to mention ajax="false". No need to mention empty parenthesis after method name if you are not passing parameters. Use action instead of actionListener if you don't have anything to do with the instance of the component which raised the event. Ideally you should have something like this  <h:commandButton value="Save" id="saveBtn"
                        action="#{requestBean.addRequest}" />

Comment: Unfortunately, same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to achieve it.

1. You can make your managed bean request scoped .
2. You can set the values to `null` in the backing bean , after submit.
3. You can use `resetValues` (set to `true`) attribute of the `p:ajax` component.
4. You can use the `p:resetInput` component inside your `p:commandButton`
5. You can use the method `RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().reset("reference to the component to reset")` in your backing bean.

There are examples of these methods on Primefaces - ShowCase, search for `ResetInput` under Misc.

Answer (score 0):

In case of `JSF` when we enter some text in input filed and that input filed is mapped with back bean, then the UI-Page is showing the current value of backing bean value on UI-Page.

**Example**: if you have field `firstName` in java class and you are setting the name by `<p:inputText />` and click on button `Save` the value is live until object live.
so you have to provide null value in `firstName` after clicking `save` button in method of `actionListener="#{requestBean.addRequest()}"`.
And
use update="@form". if both is not work then you have to write JavaScripts for that.
if not work let me know.

Comment: I tried everything written above, but the result is still the same.   <h:commandButton value="Save" id="saveBtn" actionListener="#{requestBean.addRequest()}" update="@form"/> and putting set methods for all properties in the addRequest() method did not help.

Comment: @ankushyadav,
There is no need for Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think primefaces update works with #id selector, please try with style class :

```
<h:form styleClass="form-selector"> 

<p:commandButton update="@(.form-selector)" />
```

Comment: Do not work for me, i even did not manage to fix it with the above suggestion... that is why i created a new page and redirect to it after i submit the form.

Answer (score 0):

Try these;

```
<p:commandButton  value="Clear" process="@this" type="reset" update="requestForm">
                 <p:resetInput target="requestForm"/>
 </p:commandButton>
```

If it is an object, you need to set it to null and add ajax listener with update;

`resetForm(){obj=null;}`

Then;

```
<p:ajax event="change" update="requestForm" listener="${resetForm()}"/>
```

Comment: It says: "<p:ajax> Event:change is not supported." and where exactly i should put this line.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I had to do it - who knows why:

```
      <p:commandButton value="Reset" icon="ui-icon-refresh" process="@this" update=":form">
        <p:resetInput target=":form" clearModel="true" />
      </p:commandButton>
```

Depending on your needs, clearModel may not be necessary. See the PrimeFaces documentation on resetInput's clearModel (defaults to false): "When enabled, reset input also sets null values to the bound values so it reset inputs values and model values."

As someone tells us [here](https://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=30267):

> Just in case someone else has this same problem...
>
> p:resetInput does NOT accept @form as a target. You must supply the
>   actual ID of the form/naming container that you would like to clear. I
>   have seen examples of code online (I think somewhere on StackOverflow)
>   that used @form as the target-- don't be fooled, this does not work.

This is why I used `target=":form"`, because my root NamingContainer was `<h:form id="form">`. There's loads of information on the NamingContainers selection stuff [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8634156/how-to-find-out-client-id-of-component-for-ajax-update-render-cannot-find-compo/8644762#8644762).

Also, note that you can do this to have a confirm dialog first:

```
      <p:commandButton value="Reset" icon="ui-icon-refresh" process="@this" update=":form">
        <p:resetInput target=":form" clearModel="true" />
        <p:confirm header="Confirm Reset" message="Are you sure you want to reset all changes?" icon="ui-icon-help" />
      </p:commandButton>

      <p:confirmDialog global="true" closable="true" closeOnEscape="true" showEffect="fade" hideEffect="fade">
        <p:commandButton value="No" type="button" styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-no" icon="ui-icon-close"  />
        <p:commandButton value="Yes" type="button" styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-yes" icon="ui-icon-check" />
      </p:confirmDialog>
```